# Termination capacitor value & grounding

Tags: ground, ethernet, layout, termination

I have read discussion on an [article](https://resources.altium.com/p/bob-smith-termination-it-correct-ethernet#523-ohms-vs-75-ohms) on the value of bob smith termination resistor, which is 75 Ω.

Basically, the idea of bob-smith termination is to provide a sink for common-mode noise that may transfer from the PHY side to the connector side.

The RC provides an impedance-matched path back to a ground point in the system.

My question:

1. In many places, the capacitor on the bob-smith termination voltage rating value is 2 kV. Can someone tell me the reason for such an high value of voltage rating on this cap and why is it required?
2. In my above statements, "The RC provides an impedance-matched path back to a ground point in the system.", can someone tell me to which "ground point" should this be connected to? The digital board PCB ground or the chassis ground (RJ-45 connector shield ground, which is then connected to the PCB ground via the bob-smith termination)?

Answer (score 1):

Cable(or connector)-side is isolated from PHY-side which is referenced to local ground (your circuit's ground), and the cable-side is earth-referenced (chassis, shield, whatever).

So the termination should be placed earth-referenced (2), and the idea behind placing a 2-kV-rated termination cap is surge protection and robustness (1).

---

PS: It's already mentioned in the article that Bob-Smith termination values are problematic and some experiments show that the termination itself has almost no effect. You may want to see the foot note in my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/625177/question-on-resistor-and-capacitor-arrangement-power-supply/625201#625201), and another question and answers [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161436/why-is-bob-smith-termination-for-ethernet-recommended-if-its-wrong).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. 1. Do you have any advice on connecting the two grounds/references,i.e., the cable side and the PHY side? If so, the values and the reason, please?

Comment: @Freshman it's actually out of your question's scope, but here it is: You normally don't have to connect them. But, as a counter example, ATX PSU's have their DC ground tied to chassis ground, and this makes the PHY-side on the MoBo earth-referenced. If your PHY and cable grounds are isolated then the value of the capacitance should be determined by the tests and requirements (e.g. hi-pot tests, max allowed leakage, etc). Usually, 1~2 nF / 2 kV ceramic between the grounds is fine. That cap also provides a low-res shunt for RF currents and EMI (e.g. 1n @ 100 MHz shows 1.6 Ohms resistance).

Comment: Not surprised there's no (or at least nebulous) difference on the linked answer. It wouldn't affect radiated, the signal source is already balanced.  It does however affect unbalanced conditions, like induced current on the cable (CM) which is therefore unbalanced between pairs (two otherwise open-circuit pairs when connected to 10/100). Termination impedance doesn't matter much because it just needs to be dampened well enough to absorb energy that would otherwise resonate between pairs. The real question is: given the CMCs inside the magnetics, what is the "correct" or ideal value?

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor value and rating is derived from the magnetics isolation rating, which in turn is determined by the bandwidth and economics of the transformer.

So, starting from the beginning:

The transformer uses enameled twisted pair, making a transmission line transformer.  Given the bandwidth requirements, a small ferrite core is used, and some 10s of cm of wire, giving a cutoff frequency above 100MHz or thereabouts.  Wire length determines HF cutoff frequency, and core size and turns determines LF cutoff.

Enameled wire is typically somewhere between functional and basic insulation type, good for a few hundred volts.  Heavier coats can handle a thousand volts or so, up to triple-insulated types which can handle several thousand and count as reinforced type.  But the insulation thickness increases as a result, taking up more space (necessitates bigger core, and even longer winding length), and too much dimension raises the characteristic impedance of the pair (which needs to be close to 100Ω).

Also, as it happens, normal/average type enamel gives a fairly low characteristic impedance, so there is some advantage to the somewhat heavier coated wire.

In any case, what is economical and practical to produce, is compact transformers rated for 1500V peak isolation.

On to ESD.

Standard commercial level ESD is 8kV direct or 15kV air discharge.  Assuming charge conservation, 15kV is the more stringent case.  From 150pF (see IEC 61000-4-2), this divides down to 1.5kV at 9 times, or 1350pF minimum capacitance to ground; round up to 1.5nF.  Likewise, round up the 1.5kV to a 2kV rating, and there's your standard capacitor value.

Larger values (2nF+) are acceptable for ESD purposes, and can be rated lower voltage as a result, but 2kV is a good figure for these minimal values.  Larger values however worsen isolation (CMRR, leakage current at mains frequency, etc.), so smaller values are preferred.

This determines the capacitor value.

Notice the relevant current path: ESD comes in from the outside world, and returns through... whatever route it finds.  In other words, ground/earth, enclosure, whatever.  This is where the capacitor belongs.

If you don't have a metallic enclosure, then the PCB must be what is being used as enclosure/ground (ground plane).  Then the capacitor goes to that.

If an enclosure is present, capacitance (or any other impedance) between it and PCB ground plane is a separate issue, determined by the nature of all connections crossing that barrier.

The resistors only serve to terminate resonances between pairs, mainly of relevance for immunity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ethernet standard requires 1500 RMS VAC isolation which is approximately 2200 peak DC.
2. There is no one true answer that applies. It depends if you even have a metal shield on your connector, or if you have a chassis made of insulating plastic or conductive metal, is your digital ground anyway connected to metal chassis or is it floating, or if your device supports PoE or not, or if your device has connections to other devices which can be earthed, floating etc. It would be safe to say it connects to Ethernet connector metal chassis, whether or not that is galvanically bonded to system digital ground or not.